# LLVM with op & ld - linking error

Tags: c, llvm, ld, llvm-clang, llc

I am trying to familiarize myself with LLVM & clang for a project, where I will work with different optimizations. Therefore I need to interact with LLVM not only via clang, but use opt & llc. Now I am failing at linking of a very basic example with the use of C library.

Code (main.c):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("hallo");
}
```

LLVM Flow & ld as linker:

```
clang -c -emit-llvm main.c
opt -O3 main.bc -o optimized.bc
llc -march=x86-64 -filetype=obj optimized.bc -o prog.o
ld --verbose -static -lc prog.o -o prog --entry main
```

Error output of ld:

```
...
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.a failed
attempt to open //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.a failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.a succeeded
attempt to open prog.o succeeded
prog.o
prog.o: In function `main':
optimized.bc:(.text+0xc): undefined reference to `printf'
```

I am kind of perplexed by this error:

- I am using -lc, which should link the stdc library
- The output of ld suggests that libc was found
- Why is ld complaining about an error in an LLVM IR file?

An even more dumbed down C program links, but gives me a segmentation fault & execution.

Code:

```
int main() {
    int a = 5;
}
```

That kind of makes me wonder if I am doing someting fundamentally wrong...

Thx!

Comment: Have you tried putting `-lc` after `prog.o` (i.e., `ld --verbose -static prog.o -lc -o prog --entry main`)?  The order of libraries and object files matters (personally I get it wrong the first time no matter which way I do it).

Comment: That versions gives me other linker errors. e.g. :

(.text+0x133): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.a(iofflush.o):(.eh_frame+0x13): undefined reference to `__gcc_personality_v0'

//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.a(iofputs.o): In function `_IO_fputs':
(.text+0x15e): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.a(iofputs.o):(.eh_frame+0x13): undefined reference to `__gcc_personality_v0'

Comment: @MartinM `clang main.o` pulls a lot of things to linking. You can see what it does via `clang main.o -###`.